viewport → background → world: how to use?
name of the button: Way to display the background: world
how to use this function? For me (v4.3) it has no effect


From the Blender Manual-
"World:
Use the color from the World’s Viewport Display options."
Pick the 'World' tab in the dropdown  first.
Then in Properties, go to
World Properties and set the color under Viewport Display.

Blender gives you multiple options.

That being said, choosing the  'Viewport' tab in the dropdown menu and setting it there is probably easier.
